# which function will be called after fragment becomes active

Tags: android, android-fragments

which function will be called after popBackStack is called?
I mean, when a certain fragment becomes active after calling popBackStack, which function will be called?
I did debug but onResume is called after certain activity is done something like clicking button etc.
But I need to call a function when fragment becomes active by getting called popBackStack

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same question and tried to find out which default method is called when a fragment becomes active after calling popBackStack, but couldn't find any default methods called(here I mean onResume, onAttached, etc by default methods).

Hence I worked it out by calling the active fragment's method explicitly just after calling popBackStack.

For example, suppose we have two fragments A and B in the same activity and have clicked back button of the Android device on fragment A.

```
//fragment A
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    

        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                    // handle back button
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    fm.popBackStack();

                    //call fragment B.setBackButtonLister method
                    B fragment = (B)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(B.TAG);
                    if (fragment != null){
                        fragment.setBackButtonListener();
                    }
                    return true;

                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

This way, you can call any method of fragment B after you get the handle of B.

Hope this will help you, Cheers!